# Deploy CodeIgniter 4 project on Heroku

Tags: php, web-development-server, codeigniter-4

I have a basic codeIgniter 4 project with no connection to a database. As at now it uses the default config for routing. I have followed the appropriate casing for the Controllers... that is first letter uppercase. The project works fine on local host but returns 404 error on heroku.

> 404 - File Not Found
>
> > Sorry! Cannot seem to find the page you were looking for.

$baseURL is set to the domain

$indexPage is empty

index.php and .htaccess are in the main directory.

[Here](https://github.com/afyacy/iaesteghana) is a link to the project on github. And [here](http://iaesteghana.herokuapp.com/) is the project on heroku

Any suggestions on what I should try?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is mod_rewrite installed and enabled on the heroku server? Without it your .htaccess file will throw a 404